# Spring Camel: Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, apache-camel

I am trying to integrate camel into an existing spring project that uses an embedded tomcat instance to run locally. The spring project works before I add any camel dependencies, however, after 4 camel dependencies are added, I get the message "Process finished with exit code 0". I am building the application with maven and running it inside an embedded tomcat instance (mvn clean install -Pembedded (see profile below)).

I am not a Camel newbie, but I still cant figure out how the dependencies below are causing my spring process to finish running (it seems like spring sees nothing to execute after the camel dependencies are added). How can I keep the existing spring application working and still have the new camel dependencies?

Here are the new dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the complete file (with private info removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.----.----</groupId>
    <artifactId>webs-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>webs-catalog</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

<name>catalog-service</name>
<description>Commerce Catalog Service</description>
<url>----</url>

<properties>
    <jacoco.minimum.code.coverage>0.8</jacoco.minimum.code.coverage>
    <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <central.repo>----</central.repo> <!-- "nexus-proxy" is a cache -->
    <org.apache.camel.version>2.16.0</org.apache.camel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<profiles>
    <!-- Default build profile for generating war -->
    <profile>
        <id>war</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            <log.dir>${catalina.base}/logs</log.dir>
            <!-- updates bootstrap.properties -->
            <config.override.path>file:${catalina.base}/conf</config.override.path>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>/src/main/resources/deployablecontent.xml</descriptor>
                        <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- Build profile for stand-alone java application with embedded Tomcat 
        Container -->
    <profile>
        <id>embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            <log.dir>logs</log.dir>
            <!-- updates bootstrap.properties -->
            <config.override.path>./conf</config.override.path> 
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central-mirror</id>
        <url>${central.repo}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Is there any error messages in log files?  Try removing scope for spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Comment: Please show your routes and complete logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **provided** scope for ***spring-boot-starter-tomcat*** then it become default scope **compile**. In embedded tomcat environment, You should set default scope compile and if you wish to deploy the war to any other standalone tomcat. This dependency can be marked as provided.

Comment: Also the package type should be jar instead of war. That way he will have a uber jar with tomcat embedded instead of a war. The provided scope and war package is for Spring Boot applications that are going to be deployed in a container.